# Minimize and Maximize JFrame on custom events in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

If I have two JFrames where one is the main JFrame, and the other one pops up when I click something. Now what I want is that when the new frame pops up, the main one should be minimized. Also when I click on this popup frame to close it, the main should be restored back.

Essentially I want to know, how can we maximize and minimize a JFrame apart from the default click operation. Is there any function for doing this on custom click for example?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29

Comment: @Johnydep : Why not you simply use frame.setVisible(true/false); that will almost give you the same effect. If you really doesn't have to manually bring your first frame back into focus, just in case.  Regards

Comment: @ProphesyAwaits, just by setting true/false i can not make them interact with eachother, also the frame is not globally accessable outside its constructor, that's another problem though!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) [setDefaultCloseOperation to NOTHING_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

2) [addWindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to `JFrame`

3) overrive `windowsClosing()` method with proper `Action` for iconify ...

4) don't forget to set to the [JMenuItem/JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) `System.exit(1)`, because in this form current JVM instence never gone from PC RAM or swap area until PC restarted or switch off

5) better would be to change 2nd. `JFrame` to the [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) because in most cases is too hard manage lots of methods betweens two `JFrames`

- `setPatent`
- `setModal`
- `setModalityTypes`

Comment: thanks for your reply. Just a questin, wouldn't system.exit kill the whole program?  One more thing, is it possible to add image to a JDialog?